# .htaccess redirect all pages to the same page with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all pages of my website to the same page, but with a get parameter attached.

What I've got so far:

```
#Check if Page already has parameter
RewriteCond !%{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)w=[0-9]+(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ......
```

I dont know how I can redirect to the same page again with the parameter attached.

Comment: What get parameter you want to attach?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct RewriteCond. If you want to redirect **/filename.php** to **/filename.php?q=filename** you can use this

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^filename.php$ /filename.php?q=foobar [R,L]
```